# push notification(Android/iOS) for users (they haven't given permission yet) - or an alternative

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am working on flutter app(android/ios).
there is a large group of users who currently do not use the application. We want to return them. The first option to use is a push message. But the problem is that in the beginning there was no push support in the application. If I add them now the user needs:

- get updates
- run the app
- give permission to receive push

the problem is that this group of users does not use the application (it is only installed). they will not enter the application and will not give permission - accordingly, they will not receive a push.

is there any alternative option? are these users already lost? any advice - I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission for push notifications on Android is opt-in from Android 13, so it is not that big of a deal compared to iOS. If they have automatic updates set on, they would receive the update with the FCM support and will be eligible to receive whatever marketing information you will send to them.

For iOS it is not gonna happen, so unless you have any other way to communicate with your users (e.g. via e-mail address) then I do not see how you could engage them.

Comment: While you're right it would work at the moment on most Android devices, expect the percentage it works on to shrink every month.

Comment: if the user (android) automatically updated the application but did not launch it - will receive a push message?

Comment: @FetFrumos The notification will be received by the system and displayed as if the app was in the background.